# PFQuery finding all objects within a class

Tags: swift, xcode, heroku, parse-platform

This is a really basic question but I really don't understand why my code keeps looping through the query.

I have a parse server hosting by Heroku and a table view controller and I'm trying to create a query to return n number of rows (depending on how many rows on my table)

Here is the code I have made:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: institutionTitle)
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("There has been an error")
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.postGrabber.append(object)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
print(postGrabber.count)
```

`institutionTitle` is a string which matches with my `className` on Parse and `postGrabber` is an *array* of `[PFObject]` used to store the information from entries pulled from the table.

I have 1 row on my table but when I run this code and print `postGrabber.count`, for some reason it keeps incremented the number of rows in the array and I have no idea why.

If someone could help me it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line `print(postGrabber.count)` is called multiple times, the problem doesn't come from the query but from something higher in your code. If you don't find it copy paste your code here.